# Omitting data type constructors

Tags: haskell, types

I'm trying to implement the following in Haskell:

```
0,1,2,...:N  
x,y,z,...:V  
+,*,-,/,...:F    
F alias for Expr -> Expr -> Expr  
Expr := N|V|F Expr Expr
```

My question is first:
**Is the grammar flawed at type level?** Does it make sense? All terms look like they'd type check (allowing for 0,1,... to be both Expr and N subtype, and x,y,... to be both Expr and V subtype).

And secondarily, what's the closest Haskell implementation? My current Haskell implementation is:

```
data F = +|-|*|... 
data Expr = N|V|MakeExpr F Expr Expr
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT -

The key difference between the grammar and implementation is that type constructor is implicit /omitted in the grammar. Why are type constructors compulsory in Haskell?

Comment: This is not pseudocode - it is just a grammar. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by `MakeExpr: F -> Expr -> Expr -> (Expr,Expr); MakeExpr f x y = (f,x,y)` - `MakeExpr` is already defined in `data Expr = N|V|MakeExpr F Expr Expr`. Also, you may want to record the actual values in the `N` and `V` variants. In any case, I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: Fixed, should make more sense now.

Comment: Constructors can't begin with symbols such as `+`. Consider `data F = Plus | Minus | DotDotDot`.

Comment: You can, however, use infix constructors like `data Foo = Int :+ Char | String :* Bool`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The key difference between the grammar and implementation is that type constructor is implicit /omitted in the grammar. Why are type constructors compulsory in Haskell?

.

> Is the grammar flawed at type level? Does it make sense? All terms look like they'd type check (allowing for 0,1,... to be both Expr and N subtype, and x,y,... to be both Expr and V subtype

The reason data constructors<sup>1</sup> are compulsory in Haskell is *specifically* to ensure that you **can't** have x, y, .. be both Expr and V subtypes.

So your grammar looks like a reasonable model for how you want your language terms to work. But it doesn't make sense as a **direct** design for how you want to represent your language terms as Haskell data types.

Basically, Haskell deliberately does not have subtypes. It ensures that when you create a new type (with `newtype` or `data`) that all of the values of the new type are distinct from the values of all other existing types (and all types that will be created in future). It does this by having values of user-defined types always appear inside constructors (and making it impossible to "reuse" constructors; you always make new ones whenever you make a new type).

The way Haskell's type system works depends on this lack of subtyping. You could design a language that allowed subtypes (see Scala, perhaps). But it just fundamentally wouldn't be Haskell.

But what you can do instead is define something like:

```
data Expr
  = ExprN N
  | ExprV V
  | ExprF Expr Expr
```

You still can't have a `N` value and just use it as an `Expr`. But you can just apply `ExprN` to it, and then you have an `Expr`. And it's really no more burden than if Haskell allowed you to use some `n` of type `N` as an `Expr` as well, but only required you to add a type annotation clarifying that that's what you meant; you just have to say `ExprN n` instead of `n :: Expr`.

Similarly when you have an `Expr` and you want to apply a function on `N` to it, the case statement to extract the `N` from the `ExprN` constructor (if it's there) isn't really any more code than you'd have to write to check if your `Expr` was actually an `N`.

---

<sup>1</sup> "**Type** constructor" is a specific term in Haskell, which isn't what we're talking about here. I'm pretty sure what you meant by that was "the constructors for a type", but to be pedantic you accidentally referred to a different thing by using that term.

To clear it up, when you declare a type like `data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a`, `Nothing` and `Just` are new **data constructors** ("constructor" on its on is extremely likely to mean a data constructor) and `Maybe` is a new **type constructor**.